# Organization of leaf and non-leaf node in B+ tree

Tags: c++, database, data-structures, tree, b-tree

I am new to B tree structure. I was wondering if I could make the leaf node in disk while the non-leaf node in memory, so that I could improve the searching while store a lot of data.

I tried to find in memory tree and on disk tree, but I did not find anything like this hybrid tree.

Comment: It can be done, but I highly recommend against this (due to the huge difference in access speed between a file and memory).  Each node will need to have both a pointer to subtree (memory) and a file offset value (position of leaf node in the file).  The B+ tree should be designed to reduce the number of fetches or traversals in order to get to the item or the leaf node.  If you have too many leaf nodes, consider balancing the tree.

Answer (score 0):

B-tree implementations typically have some sort of cache, and ideally the cache size is large enough to fully hold all of the non-leaf nodes. So in practice, non-leaf nodes aren't read from disk when doing a search. As the tree gets larger, the cache isn't large enough to hold all of the non-leaf nodes, and so they'll get evicted from the cache. If the cache has a smart "LRU"-style eviction policy, the most important non-leaf nodes will stay in the cache.

B-trees also have caching policies with respect to leaf nodes. For example, are they held in the same cache as the non-leaf nodes? Are they held in a separate cache, or perhaps are they never cached at all?